# Swift: How do I create a reference to another object without making it strong?

Tags: swift, object, reference, null

I have this code

```
var myObj:MyClass?
```

I want to do this

```
var objX = &myObj
```

And so if I call a function on `objX`or set `objX = nil` it is actually done on `myObj` ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can use & only in function with inout declare.

```
func what(inout value: Int) {
    // code
}
```

or through generic, if you want to access with any object type

```
func what<T>(inout value: T) { ...
```

Comment: What if I do this `var objX = what(&myObj)` will that return a reference? Given that what() returns the `value` as `-> T`

Comment: it will return just reference